# How to install Skype in Arch-based Antergos Linux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, skype, antergos

In latest Antergos Linux, Arch-based, up-to-date.

```
$ sudo pacman -S skype
error: target not found: skype


$ yaourt -S skype
error: target not found: skype
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sources: [here](https://blog.chathura.net/2014/01/installing-skype-on-arch-linux/) and [here](http://forum.antergos.com/topic/2014/how-do-i-install-skype/2).

Skype is in `multilib` repo. Enable it first by editing `pacman.conf`. In Terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pacman.conf
```

Edit file by uncommenting below lines

```
[multilib]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

Then, to update sources and install Skype:

```
sudo pacman -S skype
```

Comment: [*Never* `pacman -Sy $package`](http://gist.io/5660494)...